# Correctly export fabric.Group with 2 images toDataUrl()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, canvas, fabricjs

I have following :

```
    //Remove boundaries (RED DOTS , area is still visible)    
    this.maskCanvas.remove(this.boundaryBorders!)
    //TODO Combine both canvases and export as Image
    const backgroundCanvasImg = this.canvas.getObjects()[0]
    const layerCanvasImg = this.maskCanvas.getObjects()[0]

    console.log(backgroundCanvasImg, layerCanvasImg)

    const combinedImages = new fabric.Group([
      backgroundCanvasImg,
      layerCanvasImg
    ])

    const url = combinedImages.toDataURL({enableRetinaScaling: true, format: 'png'})
    console.log(url);
```

In execution I get this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (SecurityError): Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

I have tried to make this :

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/despicable_me_2_6.jpg?w=1024', img => {
        img.scaleToWidth(250)
        img.bringToFront()
        img.crossOrigin = "anonymous" // Set to anonymous
        this.maskCanvas.add(img)
        this.maskCanvas.setActiveObject(img)
        this.maskCanvas.renderAll()
```

Ina addition each object in both canvases are Images
Are there any other ways to do this ? Or where my mistake is?

Thank you!